# Configuring grunt for uglify

Tags: gruntjs

I am using gruntfile for running uglify task for 2 separate modules. Both the modules are configured in the same gruntfile as:

```
     uglify: 
     {
        ac: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                mangle: false, // Separate target for mangled output
                report: 'min', // Reports actual minified size
                banner: '<%= banner %>'
                },
                    files: {
                        'dist/<%= pkg.name %>_ac.min.js': ['<%= concat.ac.dest %>']
                    }
                },
            mangled: {
                options: {
                mangle: true,   
                report: 'gzip', 
                banner: '<%= banner %>'
                },
                files: {
                    'dist/<%= pkg.name %>_ac.2.min.js': ['<%= concat.ac.dest %>']
                }
            }
        },

        lib: {
            files: {
                'dist/<%= pkg.name %>_lib.min.js': ['<%= concat.lib.dest %>']
            },
            mangled: {
                files: {
                    'dist/<%= pkg.name %>_lib.2.min.js': ['<%= concat.lib.dest %>']
                }
            }
        },
    } 
grunt.registerTask('ac', ['uglify:ac:dist']);
```

When i run the above grunt file, it runs without any error but i dont get any output. I am not sure if my way of configuring is correct.

Comment: How are you running grunt? `grunt ac` ?

Comment: yes of course..  I tried registering as grunt.registerTask('ac', ['uglify:ac']); also, but even that didnt work.

Comment: I don't think it's your `registerTask` that's the problem. Is that your full `Gruntfile.js`? Do you have a `concat` task specified you're not running?

Answer (score 0):

Okay here's my answer from the limited info in the question;

The way you have your `Gruntfile.js` file set up it is looking for files in a `concat` task which you don't seem to have included. If it can't find these files it wont output anything.

My guess is that you copied some of this from the [sample gruntfile](http://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile).

Specifically this section `['<%= concat.ac.dest %>']` is explained in the documentation:

> This tells uglify to create a file within `dist/` that contains the
>   result of minifying the JavaScript files. Here I use `<%=
>   concat.dist.dest %>` so uglify will minify the file that the concat
>   task produces.

If you don't have a `concat` task specified or being called, there will be no output files to run `uglify` on so there will be no output. Either check that `concat` is called with `grunt.registerTask('ac', ['concat', 'uglify:ac:dist']);` and is producing output (if you have a tast set up) or change this to the location of the JS files you wish to uglify are.

```
'dist/<%= pkg.name %>_ac.min.js': ['/path/to/yourJavascriptFile.js']
```

Comment: is your `concat` task producing any files?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the dist task and have only

```
 ac: {
            options: {
            mangle: false, // Separate target for mangled output
            report: 'min', // Reports actual minified size
            banner: '<%= banner %>'
            },
                files: {
                    'dist/<%= pkg.name %>_ac.min.js': ['<%= concat.ac.dest %>']
                }
       },
```

Hope concat.ac.dest is having the correct file name and the path. If you need to add more files you can add as

```
['src/input1.js', 'src/input2.js']
```

Fore more details refer https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify

Hope this would solve your issue.